# onclick event isn't triggered for the previous element when generate new one dynamlically (duplicate ids)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, grails, gsp

I'm working in gsp view in Grails.

A link in a div triggers a Jquery event onclick.

The problem is when a new div is generated dynamically , only the link in the new form triggers this event. Whereas the old one is not functioning anymore.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Here is the div that is duplicated and cause the problem in view.gsp

```
<div id="supplementaryInfo">

  <div id="deleteSupplementary" class="deleteSupplementary" >

               <a href="#"  id="deleteSupp">

                <r:img  class="icon float-right" uri="/img/app-icon-delete.gif" title="delete"/></a>
               </div>


    <g:render template="showConfirm" model="[id: id ]"/>
 </div>
```

here is the jquery function for event !

```
function showConfirmationPanelForSuppDelete(){
        $('#deleteSupp').on('click', function(event) {

            event.preventDefault();
            $("#showConfirmation).show();
        });

        cancelSuppDelete();

    }
```

Comment: show your code..

Comment: I'm guessing duplicate ids

Comment: Could you please update your question with your codes?

Comment: i've added some of my code, sorry if my question wasn't clear enough!
im guessing id duplication as well ! but how can i avoid that ?!

Comment: You've got some typos that result in syntax errors. Did you copy and paste this or type it in? If you copied you need to go back and correct any syntax errors. These errors will be revealed to you in your web browser's developer tools console (click F12).

Comment: its part of my code that i retyped it here so ignore the syntax please !

Comment: Since you are creating things dynamically, I usually append an unique id (server generated db id works if available or you can create a js method to do this as well) and have your on click account for the unique id suffix with data attributes lookup.

Answer (score 0):

If you are cloning the div than I assume that there are duplicate ids, therefore you can use jquery's [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) function:

```
<div id="cloneMe" class="yourclass">
    <input type="text" id="someId" value="" name="somename">
<a href="#"><i id="icodnId" class="icon-remove btn"></i></a>
</div>
```

tha you can use:

```
 $(document).on('click','#icodnId',function(evt){

        $(this).closest('.yourclass').dowhateveryouwant();
        evt.preventDefault();

    });
```

Comment: i think i've solved this event triggering by using live instead of on click but the problem is it's still referring to the newest (generated) div element.